# How to get value from one function to another function in php

Tags: php, function

Here is my code:

```
function a()
{
 $name = "hello world"; 
}
function b()
{
 echo $name; // I want output hello world here
}
```

what should I do?

Comment: Can you add how you are calling that function and the current output?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
function a(){
$name = 'Hello World';
return $name;
}

function b(){
$name = $this->a();
echo $name; //should output 'Hello World'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but you could try making the first function return that variable, so you can use it in the second function. Something like this:

```
function a()
{
    $name = "hello world"; 
    return $name;
}
function b()
{
    echo a();
}
```

Comment: `$this->a()` should be `a()`

Comment: Have you test your code before write?

Comment: thanks, for some reason i assumed this is inside a class